# SQL preserve order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have an SQL table (PostgreSQL 9.3) with essentially an ID column and a value column (e.g. varchar). I need to be able to reproduce the order in which the rows were entered. The most naive approach would be to either rely on the AUTOINCREMENT feature of the ID column or have a specific column for ordering, let's say

```
CREATE TABLE "foo" (
    "foo_id" SERIAL,
    "order_index" int NOT NULL,
    "value" VARCHAR(128)
);
```

The data might then look like

```
347 1 'foo'
368 2 'bar'
511 3 'baz'
```

and I could retrieve them with an ORDER BY "order_index" clause.

The problem is that there has to be the possibility to insert another row at a specific position later on, e.g. when a row has been left out accidentally. In the above solution I would have to reassign all order_index values that come after the inserted position. That does not scale very well and is kind of the opposite of elegant.

One solution would be to leave gaps in the initial assignment, so the above example would look like

```
347 1000 'foo'
368 2000 'bar'
511 3000 'baz'
```

Rows could be inserted until a gap is filled. Only then a reassignment has to take place. This is the best idea I have had so far. I have also thought about a solution based on the idea of a linked list where each row has a column "successor_id". However, in that case I could not retrieve the data in an ordered way by using a simple ORDER BY clause.

I've been wondering whether there is a scalable and elegant solution possibly involving two columns that does not require reassignment of order indices. Or is there some kind of best practice dealing with this problem?

Comment: What would make you want to insert a row between rows 1 and 2? I mean how do you come to know that a new row must be placed exactly there? Is there anything in your data indicating this?

Comment: I've just described the real-life problem behind it in my comment to Consider Me. Hope it's ok to refer to a different comment instead of copy/pasting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users enter data (of a sheet). When they look up their data, they may want to insert another data row between others.

So they are always working on a small part of the whole table. Then it is not so big a task to renumber the records. Let's say you have a sheet number indicating the sheet they are working on and an order index per sheet number. Then it would be no big task for the dbms to handle this:

```
update sheets set order_index = order_index + 1 
where sheet_no = 1234 and order_index >= 23;

insert into sheets (order_index, ...) values (23, new data);

commit;
```

I would even go so far as deleting the rows and inserting them anew.

```
delete from sheets where sheet_no = 1234;

insert into sheets ...
...

commit;
```

Comment: You are right. From a performance point of view it shouldn't be a big deal. I had hoped to do this without even touching the otherwise unmodified rows. However, in the end the simplicity of your suggestion might just win out. There is no point implementing something very complicated if the gain is purely theoretical.

Comment: Yes, I think you can see the entered data as a whole. If the user decides to change this dataset, simply remove the old dataset and insert the new data in a loop (with order_index being the loop counter). I'd even call this solution elegant :-)

Answer (score 0):

A variation on your "gaps" idea: Use a secondary ordering column.

Increment your order column on your own (don't use AUTOINCREMENT), but treat it like an autoincrement column, incrementing just by +1 (not by gaps as you suggest). Then, just add a 2nd column that defaults to 0. Order on both of these columns.

When you come to the case of inserting a missing row, insert it with the main ID column matching the row that preceeds it, and a "1" (or 2, or, 3) in the secondary ordering column.

It ruins the uniqueness of your ID column, though.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it works only once. If I want to insert a row between those with the ordering columns (1, 0) and (2, 0) I can use (1, 1) or even insert multiple rows with (1, 1), (1, 2), ... . However, when I come back again and want to insert e.g. between (1, 0) and (1, 1), I have the same problem as before with one ordering column. I would have to use as many ordering columns as the number of revisions I want to support.

Comment: Then you can go for a `numeric` type instead. Then you have the floating point and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit worried about the fact that you are reinserting rows to already assigned sequence number. Much better approach to this would be using `timestamp` column to identify the time a row has been inserted. You could also create a `history table` and add triggers on `table` to log every change within one row `(insert, delete, update)`. This way you can recreate the row if neccessary

**Solution:**

Add a column `add_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()` and this should do the trick most elegantly (I believe).

Before delete and insert operation of `id = 368`

```
347 'foo' 2015-04-26 12:16:00
368 'bar' 2015-04-27 13:55:23
511 'baz' 2015-04-28 10:01:00
```

After inserting it again with the same sequence number

```
347 'foo' 2015-04-26 12:16:00
368 'bar' 2015-04-28 12:17:11
511 'baz' 2015-04-28 10:01:00
```

Comment: Hm, maybe my phrasing with "order in which the rows were entered" was misleading. I should have said that I need to maintain a custom order (which happens to coincide initially with the order in which the rows where entered). My problem is that I need to maintain the order of the columns 1, 2, 3 above, but still be able to insert a row let's say between rows 2 and 3. I don't see how the timestamp can help here.

Comment: @PowerGnom so you specifically insist on having a sequence like 1,2,3 and be able to insert between them. May I ask why is that important to keep this information explicitly in a table? An index maintains this using doubly linked list.

Comment: I don't necessarily insist on a sequence like 1, 2, 3. The problem is the following: Users enter data that they have on a sheet of paper. For QA reasons they want to see the resulting table on the screen in the same order as they have entered the data (i.e. in the same order as on the original sheet). During said QA they might identify a missing row e.g. because they accidentally skipped that row when entering the data. Now they need to insert the missing row at the right position. I'm now trying to figure out how to maintain that order in the database.

Comment: I would still say that a `timestamp` column solves the issue. Then you can select and use a window function to give you a numeric order based on timestamp when a row was inserted. Could you please make an SQL fiddle for the situation you're describing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking me to do. What do you mean with "an SQL fiddle for the situation you're describing"?

Comment: I would like to see the whole process. Post this http://sqlfiddle.com/ under PostgreSQL 9.3 - create a schema and perform actions on the data, so that I might spot if I'm thinking right, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `order_index` a floting point number, or even better a [numeric](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN index_order TYPE NUMERIC(26, 16);
```

Choose values for the *precision* and *scale* that best suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. It's essentially a variation of the gap idea. Depending on the precision it will allow you a certain number of revisions before you have to readjust the order indices.

Comment: Well, 16 digits for something you describe as "accidental skip" should be more than enough, given the maximum integer value you can store has 10 digits (which is in fact the total possible amount of rows in your table, given the current definition of `foo_id`). If not, you can always adjust it at a later stage.

Comment: You are right. You would insert at the average of the surrounding indices in order to have equal space on both sides. If you start with neighbouring integer indices then you could do even in the worst case a bit more than 50 insertion rounds before the difference drops below 1e-16. I agree that this should be more than enough, but this number is not so outrageously large that you don't need to consider it.